# Why pip is required or what is the use of it in Python?

Tags: python, pip

I am little confused. Newbie into Python, apologies if I am asking silly ones. What is the need of pip if we can run a file using python filename?

What is the difference between  `python setup.py install` and `pip install package_name` if both are used for installing packages? Which is good?

Comment: [The PyPA recommended tool for **installing Python packages**.](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

Comment: Thanks..:) Fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)):

> `pip` is a recursive acronym that can stand for either "Pip Installs Packages" or "Pip Installs Python"

---

As you are newbie, you may not even know why you would need a "package manager".

Python is shipped with some basic built-in modules like the `math` module for extra maths operators and the `re` module for executing regular expressions. These are pre-included as they are considered quite useful and will be used quite a lot. However, more obscure or larger modules such as `numpy` (C based arrays) and others are *not* included - this is where `pip` comes in.

You can use the "package manager" to install, uninstall, update etc. any package within PyPI which is the **Py**thon **P**ackage **I**ndex. The result of this is that Python remains small, but there are immediately millions of free packages available for use if desired.

Comment: We can also install custom packages along with the built-in packages right?

Comment: @MaheshMohan What do you mean by "custom packages"? Most Python packages are available for download with `pip`. When you write your own script, it is not a package, it is a program that may use packages but you run yourself so maybe you are confused in that aspect. You don't need `pip` at all if you just want to write the most basic `print('hello world')` script as no non built-in packages are required.

Answer (score 1):

pip is a recommended tool for installing Python packages. For example, if you need to install an external package/library, say [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests), you have to install it first using pip.

> pip install requests

In your current scenario, you may not have to use external libraries. However, you may need it in future.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia

> pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python. Many packages can be found in the default source for packages and their dependencies — Python Package Index (PyPI).
>
> Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip (pip3 for Python 3) by default.pip is a recursive acronym that can stand for either "Pip Installs Packages" or "Pip Installs Python". Alternatively, pip stands for "preferred installer program".